# Subtract a number's digits from the number until it reaches 0

Tags: algorithm, bignum

Can anyone help me with some algorithm for this problem?

We have a big number (19 digits) and, in a loop, we subtract one of the digits of that number from the number itself.

We continue to do this until the number reaches zero. We want to calculate the minimum number of subtraction that makes a given number reach zero.

The algorithm must respond fast, for a 19 digits number (10^19), within two seconds. As an example, providing input of `36` will give `7`:

```
1. 36 - 6 = 30
2. 30 - 3 = 27
3. 27 - 7 = 20
4. 20 - 2 = 18
5. 18 - 8 = 10
6. 10 - 1 =  9
7.  9 - 9 =  0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  Show us some code.

Comment: I think you will only be able to brute-force this, by trying all possible combinations; I can’t see any way to “predict” early on whether choosing one digit over another would lead to a better result. (Although for your given example it seems to be the case that the largest digit is always chosen first, but I doubt this will lead to the ideal solution in every possible case.) Btw., what do you need this for – is this some kind of school exercise? I doubt this has any real-world application …

Comment: i have no idea how to solve that , except brute force.
yes , it's an algorithm design exercise.

Comment: i don't know if it helps or not , but any number (except 1 digit numbers) ends up in this series: 10 , 9 ,0 like: 
36 -> 30 ..... > 10 , 9 , 0  or 
178 -> 170 ..... > 10 , 9 , 0

Comment: someone find the similar problem on codeforces: [link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/331/C1) 
 i didn't mean to cheat on contest , i just need that for my homework , and i posted this problem here too: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085113/subtract-a-number-from-its-digits-until-it-reaches-0)

Comment: Why don't you try using dynamic programming for the first 10,000, and then inspect the values looking for patterns? The solution is not going to involve some iteration over 10^19 steps.

Comment: thanks , I found the solution [Here](http://codeforces.com/contest/331/submission/4138646) , now i'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

The *minimum* number of subtractions to reach zero makes this, I suspect, a very thorny problem, one that will require a great deal of backtracking potential solutions, making it possibly too expensive for your time limitations.

But the *first* thing you should do is a sanity check. Since the largest digit is a `9`, a 19-digit number will require about `1018` subtractions to reach zero. Code up a simple program to continuously subtract 9 from `1019` until it becomes less than ten. If you can't do *that* within the two seconds, you're in trouble.

By way of example, the following program <sup>(a)</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long x = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    x /= 1000000000;
    while (x > 9)
        x -= 9;
    return x;
}
```

when run with the argument `10000000000000000000` (`1019`), takes a second and a half clock time (and CPU time since it's all calculation) even at `gcc` insane optimisation level of `-O3`:

```
real    0m1.531s
user    0m1.528s
sys     0m0.000s
```

And that's with the one-billion divisor just before the `while` loop, meaning the full number of iterations would take about 48 years.

So a brute force method isn't going to help here, what you need is some serious mathematical analysis which probably means you should post a similar question over at https://math.stackexchange.com/ and let the math geniuses have a shot.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're wondering why I'm getting the value from the user rather than using a constant of `10000000000000000000ULL`, it's to prevent `gcc` from calculating it at compile time and turning it into something like:

```
mov  $1, %eax
```

Ditto for the `return x` which will prevent it noticing I don't *use* the final value of `x` and hence optimise the loop out of existence altogether.

Comment: thank you.
beside that time limit , i had a 64mb RAM limit too , so i don't think backtrack is the perfect answer.
i can calculate how many time i should subtract the number from 9 , by dividing the number by 9 (num/9 + 1), but would that help?

Comment: @RHB, yes, that would give you a lower limit of the number of subtractions. Or you could divide by `5` giving a rough estimate, assuming on average you subtract the , err, average, I guess. But, for certainty, you need to actually test it which, as per my update, can't be done in a reasonable timeframe (unless your computer is a billion times faster than mine).

Comment: it must be some math problem , i should try "math geniuses" , thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution that can solve 19 digit numbers in 2 seconds. Not even close. But I did implement a couple of algorithms (including a dynamic programming algorithm that solves for the optimum), and gained some insight that I believe is interesting.

### Greedy Algorithm

As a baseline, I implemented a greedy algorithm that simply picks the largest digit in each step:

```
uint64_t countGreedy(uint64_t inputVal) {
    uint64_t remVal = inputVal;
    uint64_t nStep = 0;
    while (remVal > 0) {
        uint64_t digitVal = remVal;
        uint_fast8_t maxDigit = 0;
        while (digitVal > 0) {
            uint64_t nextDigitVal = digitVal / 10;
            uint_fast8_t digit = digitVal - nextDigitVal * 10;
            if (digit > maxDigit) {
                maxDigit = digit;
            }
            digitVal = nextDigitVal;
        }
        remVal -= maxDigit;
        ++nStep;
    }
    return nStep;
}
```

### Dynamic Programming Algorithm

The idea for this is that we can calculate the optimum incrementally. For a given value, we pick a digit, which adds one step to the optimum number of steps for the value with the digit subtracted.

With the target function (optimum number of steps) for a given value named `optSteps(val)`, and the digits of the value named `d_i`, the following relationship holds:

```
optSteps(val) = 1 + min(optSteps(val - d_i))
```

This can be implemented with a dynamic programming algorithm. Since `d_i` is at most 9, we only need the previous 9 values to build on. In my implementation, I keep a circular buffer of 10 values:

```
static uint64_t countDynamic(uint64_t inputVal) {
    uint64_t minSteps[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    uint_fast8_t digit0 = 0;
    for (uint64_t val = 10; val <= inputVal; ++val) {
        digit0 = val % 10;
        uint64_t digitVal = val;
        uint64_t minPrevStep = 0;
        bool prevStepSet = false;
        while (digitVal > 0) {
            uint64_t nextDigitVal = digitVal / 10;
            uint_fast8_t digit = digitVal - nextDigitVal * 10;
            if (digit > 0) {
                uint64_t prevStep = 0;
                if (digit > digit0) {
                    prevStep = minSteps[10 + digit0 - digit];
                } else {
                    prevStep = minSteps[digit0 - digit];
                }
                if (!prevStepSet || prevStep < minPrevStep) {
                    minPrevStep = prevStep;
                    prevStepSet = true;
                }
            }
            digitVal = nextDigitVal;
        }
        minSteps[digit0] = minPrevStep + 1;
    }
    return minSteps[digit0];
}
```

### Comparison of Results

This may be considered a surprise: I ran both algorithms on all values up to 1,000,000. The results are **absolutely identical**. This suggests that the greedy algorithm actually calculates the optimum.

I don't have a formal proof that this is indeed true for all possible values. It intuitively kind of makes sense to me. If in any given step, you choose a smaller digit than the maximum, you compromise the immediate progress with the goal of getting into a more favorable situation that allows you to catch up and pass the greedy approach. But in all the scenarios I thought about, the situation after taking a sub-optimal step just does not get significantly more favorable. It might make the next step bigger, but that is at most enough to get even again.

### Complexity

While both algorithms look linear in the size of the value, they also loop over all digits in the value. Since the number of digits corresponds to log(n), I believe the complexity is O(n * log(n)).

I think it's possible to make it linear by keeping counts of the frequency of each digit, and modifying them incrementally. But I doubt it would actually be faster. It requires more logic, and turns a loop over all digits in the value (which is in the range of 2-19 for the values we are looking at) into a fixed loop over 10 possible digits.

### Runtimes

Not surprisingly, the greedy algorithm is faster to calculate a single value. For example, for value 1,000,000,000, the runtimes on my MacBook Pro are:

- greedy: 3 seconds
- dynamic: 36 seconds

On the other hand, the dynamic programming approach is obviously much faster at calculating all the values, since its incremental approach needs them as intermediate results anyway. For calculating all values from 10 to 1,000,000:

- greedy: 19 minutes
- dynamic: 0.03 seconds

As already shown in the runtimes above, the greedy algorithm gets about as high as 9 digit input values within the targeted runtime of 2 seconds. The implementations aren't really tuned, and it's certainly possible to squeeze out some more time, but it would be fractional improvements.

### Ideas

As already explored in another answer, there's no chance of getting the result for 19 digit numbers in 2 seconds by subtracting digits one by one. Since we subtract at most 9 in each step, completing this for a value of 10^19 needs more than 10^18 steps. We mostly use computers that perform in the rough range of 10^9 operations/second, which suggests that it would take about 10^9 seconds.

Therefore, we need something that can take shortcuts. I can think of scenarios where that's possible, but haven't been able to generalize it to a full strategy so far.

For example, if your current value is 9999, you know that you can subtract 9 until you reach 9000. So you can calculate that you will make 112 steps ((9999 - 9000) / 9 + 1) where you subtract 9, which can be done in a few operations.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments already, and agreeing with @paxdiablo’s other answer, I’m not sure if there is an algorithm to find the ideal solution without some backtracking; and the size of the number and the time constraint might be tough as well.

A general consideration though: You might want to find a way to decide between always subtracting the highest digit (which will decrease your current number by the largest possible amount, obviously), and by looking at your current digits and subtracting which of those will give you the largest “new” digit.

Say, your current number only consists of digits between `0` and `5` – then you might be tempted to subtract the `5` to decrease your number by the highest possible value, and continue with the next step. If the last digit of your current number is `3` however, then you might want to subtract `4` instead – since that will give you `9` as new digit at the end of the number, instead of “only” `8` you would be getting if you subtracted `5`.

Whereas if you have a `2` and *two* `9` in your digits already, and the last digit is a `1` – then you might want to subtract the `9` anyway, since you will be left with the second `9` in the result (at least in most cases; in some edge cases it might get obliterated from the result as well), so subtracting the `2` instead would not have the advantage of giving you a “high” `9` that you would otherwise not have in the next step, and would have the disadvantage of not lowering your number by as high an amount as subtracting the `9` would …

But every digit you subtract will not only affect the next step directly, but the following steps indirectly – so again, I doubt there is a way to always chose the ideal digit for the current step without any backtracking or similar measures.

Comment: I did some calculations with a real life program that seems to indicate even the _best_ case of no backtracking will still take about half a century :-) Not saying your points are invalid (they are) but I don't think it's doable without mathematical analysis.

Comment: @paxdiablo: The question is, do you really have to do _actual_ mathematical operations on the _whole_ number? In most cases, subtracting only one digit will affect only the last one or two digits of your current number (edge cases like subtracting `1` from `10000…0` aside) – so keeping all the digits of your number in an array (instead of using an actual numerical data type), and then only manipulating array elements “from the right” for only as much digits as necessary, as you would do when carrying out a subtraction operation on paper, might be faster.

Comment: Good point. However, I suspect an array-based solution would be slower. Discount the edge cases for now, they're unlikely to happen anyway, but now each subtraction operation basically affects one or two digits so now you have somewhere between the same number of, or double the number of, subtractions to reach zero. It won't be a `ULL` data type so that may gain some speed but, even if we assume best case of those subtractions being ten times faster (unlikely) and all subtractions affecting only one digit, that's still five years or so. I suspect the math geeks will have to handle this one :-)

Comment: I think the same way, it must been a mathematical formula or something or we just need to do some work for some little part of the number and the same needs a little calculation (like division) . 
this problem is from one of my exercises , the TA himself solved that before (within 2 seconds) because he gave me some input and output like:
in:‫‪2984719979875‬‬  out: ‫‪347562320055‬‬ , in:‫‪2654179425975195‬‬ out:‫‪304516201082766‬‬  , in: ‫‪987631579787564399‬‬  out: ‫‪112128174907159069‬‬